# Record at constant fps with CanvasCaptureMediaStream even on slow computers

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to record a video from a HTML `<canvas>` element at a specific frame rate.

I am using CanvasCaptureMediaStream with `canvas.captureStream(fps)` and also have access to the video track via `const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0]` so I create `track.requestFrame()` to write it to the output video buffer via `MediaRecorder`.

I want to precisely capture one frame at a time and then change the canvas content. Changing the canvas content can take some time (as images need to be loaded etc). So I can not capture the canvas in real-time.
Some changes on the canvas would happen in 500ms real-time so this needs also to be adjusted to rendering one frame at the time.

Comment: MediaRecorder is made to record *live* streams. Are you sure you can't prepare your canvas animation so that it runs @30FPS to begin with? Prepare all your assets before recording, pre-generate long to draw frames, so you just have to drawImage it etc. MediaRecorder can be paused and resumed, but not the MediaStream, and since MediaRecorder takes the fps from the MediaStream, I'm not sure you can get anything reliable... (though I might try some things on my end when I get more time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! MediaRecorder can be used for frame by frame recordings I thought.  That's why streams can be controlled frame by frame and initialised with a fps of "0". I tried to get it to work with your answer here on SO about using the audiocontext for a timing loop. But I actually don't need a timing loop. I can move my items on the canvas at a fixed frame rate and just record each frame, up to 60 per second, depending on the framerate I want to achieve. Where is my error? ;)

Answer (score 9):

The MediaRecorder API is meant to record **live**-streams, doing edition is not what it was designed to do, and it doesn't do it very well to be honest...

The MediaRecorder itself has no concept of frame-rate, this is normally defined by the MediaStreamTrack. However, the CanvasCaptureStreamTrack doesn't really make it clear what its frame rate is.
We can pass a parameter to `HTMLCanvas.captureStream()`, but this only tells the max frames we want per seconds, it's not really an fps parameter.
Also, even if we stop drawing on the canvas, the recorder will still continue to extend the duration of the recorded video in real time (I think that technically only a single *long* frame is recorded though in this case).

*So... we gonna have to hack around...*

One thing we can do with the MediaRecorder is to `pause()` and `resume()` it.
*Then sounds quite easy to pause before doing the long drawing operation and to resume right after it's been made?* Yes... and not that easy either...
Once again, the frame-rate is dictated by the MediaStreamTrack, but this MediaStreamTrack can not be paused.
Well, actually there is one way to pause a special kind of MediaStreamTrack, and luckily I'm talking about CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTracks.
When we do call our capture-stream with a parameter of `0`, we are basically having manual control over when new frames are added to the stream.
So here we can synchronize both our MediaRecorder adn our MediaStreamTrack to whatever frame-rate we want.

The basic workflow is

```
await the_long_drawing_task;
resumeTheRecorder();
writeTheFrameToStream(); // track.requestFrame();
await wait( time_per_frame );
pauseTheRecorder();
```

Doing so, the recorder is awaken only the time per frame we decided, and a single frame is passed to the MediaStream during this time, effectively mocking a constant FPS drawing for what the MediaRecorder is concerned.

But as always, hacks in this still experimental area come with a lot of browsers weirdness and the following demo actually only works in current Chrome...

For whatever reasons, Firefox will always generate files with twice the number of frames than what has been requested, and it will also occasionally prepend a long first frame...

Also to be noted, [Chrome has a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1047984) where it will update the canvas stream at drawing, even though we initiated this stream with a  *frameRequestRate* of `0`. So this means that if you start drawing before everything is ready, or if the drawing on your canvas itself takes a long time, then our recorder will record half-baked frames that we didn't asked for.
To workaround this bug, we thus need to use a second canvas, used only for the streaming. All we'll do on that canvas is to drawImage the source one, which will always be a fast enough operation. to not face that bug.

```js
class FrameByFrameCanvasRecorder {
  constructor(source_canvas, FPS = 30) {
  
    this.FPS = FPS;
    this.source = source_canvas;
    const canvas = this.canvas = source_canvas.cloneNode();
    const ctx = this.drawingContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // we need to draw something on our canvas
    ctx.drawImage(source_canvas, 0, 0);
    const stream = this.stream = canvas.captureStream(0);
    const track = this.track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    // Firefox still uses a non-standard CanvasCaptureMediaStream
    // instead of CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack
    if (!track.requestFrame) {
      track.requestFrame = () => stream.requestFrame();
    }
    // prepare our MediaRecorder
    const rec = this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    const chunks = this.chunks = [];
    rec.ondataavailable = (evt) => chunks.push(evt.data);
    rec.start();
    // we need to be in 'paused' state
    waitForEvent(rec, 'start')
      .then((evt) => rec.pause());
    // expose a Promise for when it's done
    this._init = waitForEvent(rec, 'pause');

  }
  async recordFrame() {

    await this._init; // we have to wait for the recorder to be paused
    const rec = this.recorder;
    const canvas = this.canvas;
    const source = this.source;
    const ctx = this.drawingContext;
    if (canvas.width !== source.width ||
      canvas.height !== source.height) {
      canvas.width = source.width;
      canvas.height = source.height;
    }

    // start our timer now so whatever happens between is not taken in account
    const timer = wait(1000 / this.FPS);

    // wake up the recorder
    rec.resume();
    await waitForEvent(rec, 'resume');

    // draw the current state of source on our internal canvas (triggers requestFrame in Chrome)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
    // force write the frame
    this.track.requestFrame();

    // wait until our frame-time elapsed
    await timer;

    // sleep recorder
    rec.pause();
    await waitForEvent(rec, 'pause');

  }
  async export () {

    this.recorder.stop();
    this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    await waitForEvent(this.recorder, "stop");
    return new Blob(this.chunks);

  }
}

///////////////////
// how to use:
(async() => {
  const FPS = 30;
  const duration = 5; // seconds

  let x = 0;
  let frame = 0;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.textAlign = 'right';
  draw(); // we must have drawn on our canvas context before creating the recorder

  const recorder = new FrameByFrameCanvasRecorder(canvas, FPS);

  // draw one frame at a time
  while (frame++ < FPS * duration) {
    await longDraw(); // do the long drawing
    await recorder.recordFrame(); // record at constant FPS
  }
  // now all the frames have been drawn
  const recorded = await recorder.export(); // we can get our final video file
  vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(recorded);
  vid.onloadedmetadata = (evt) => vid.currentTime = 1e100; // workaround https://crbug.com/642012
  download(vid.src, 'movie.webm');

  // Fake long drawing operations that make real-time recording impossible
  function longDraw() {
    x = (x + 1) % canvas.width;
    draw(); // this triggers a bug in Chrome
    return wait(Math.random() * 300)
      .then(draw);
  }

  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillText(frame + " / " + FPS * duration, 290, 140);
  };
})().catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<video id="vid" controls></video>

<script>
  // Some helpers
  
  // Promise based timer
  function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  }
  // implements a sub-optimal monkey-patch for requestPostAnimationFrame
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549862/3702797 for details
  if (!window.requestPostAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestPostAnimationFrame = function monkey(fn) {
      const channel = new MessageChannel();
      channel.port2.onmessage = evt => fn(evt.data);
      requestAnimationFrame((t) => channel.port1.postMessage(t));
    };
  }
  // Promisifies EventTarget.addEventListener
  function waitForEvent(target, type) {
    return new Promise((res) => target.addEventListener(type, res, {
      once: true
    }));
  }
  // creates a downloadable anchor from url
  function download(url, filename = "file.ext") {
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = a.download = filename;
    a.href = url;
    document.body.append(a);
    return a;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code and the idea !
I think you can improve a little bit your function "wait" because setTimeout cannot be process faster than the browser refresh rate wich is 60 fps . Instead you could do something like that :  

let time = new Date().getTime();  
while(new Date().getTime() - time < frameTime) { }

Comment: @TomLecoz setTimeout can definitely fire faster than refresh rate. For non nested timeouts in an active window the minimum is 1ms in Chrome and 0ms in Firefox. If you want a better timer that does work better in blurred tab though, you can check the previous revisions.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... If you try this code :   let time = new Date().getTime() ; setTimeout( ()=> { console.log(new Date().getTime() - time ); } , 1 )   , you get 17 ms even if you set 1 as paramater for the settimeout . Anyway, I tried my solution and it didn't work because recorder.pause need to be call at least one frame after recorder.resume in order to get the expected behaviour

Comment: @TomLecoz certainly you tried at page load and in FF only? There are even more complex rules regrading setTimeout in the page load in FF, but otherwise, nope, you should get ~1 logged from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/p6hyf3dq/

Comment: @Kaiido do you think you can help me figure out how to apply your method to a server less Vue app kind of like in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833373/ffmpeg-js-to-create-mp4-from-canavas-frames-and-transcode-it?noredirect=1#comment126941134_71833373) where I try to do what you are doing with ffmpeg but I would rather do it with your method.

Comment: @YordanRadev honestly I'm not sure the MediaRecorder API is the best solution... You may instead look into WebCodecs and libraries like MP4box. See [this thread](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/issues/243) for instance I think it contains full code (that I didn't test myself)

Answer (score 6):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946308/record-single-frames-to-a-video-with-mediarecorder-or-else) which has been linked to this one. In the meantime I came up with a solution which overlaps Kaiido's and which I think is worth reading.

I added two tricks:

- I deferred the next render (see code), which fixes the problem of Firefox generating twice the number of frames
- I stored an accumulated timing error to correct setTimeout's inaccuracies. I personally used it to tweak the progression of my render and for example skip frames if there is a sudden latency and keep the duration of the video close to the target duration. It is not enough to smoothen setTimeout though.

```js
const recordFrames = (onstop, canvas, fps=30) => {
    const chunks = [];

    // get Firefox to initialise the canvas
    canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, 0, 0);

    const stream = canvas.captureStream();
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({data}) => chunks.push(data));
    recorder.addEventListener('stop', () => onstop(new Blob(chunks)));

    const frameDuration = 1000 / fps;
    
    const frame = (next, start) => {
        recorder.pause();
        api.error += Date.now() - start - frameDuration;
        setTimeout(next, 0); // helps Firefox record the right frame duration
    };

    const api = {
        error: 0,
        init() { 
            recorder.start(); 
            recorder.pause();
        },
        step(next) {
            recorder.resume();
            setTimeout(frame, frameDuration, next, Date.now());
        }, 
        stop: () => recorder.stop()
    };

    return api;
}
```

how to use

```js
const fps = 30;
const duration = 5000;

const animation = Something;

const videoOutput = blob => {
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(video);
}

const recording = recordFrames(videoOutput, canvas, fps);

const startRecording = () => {
   recording.init();
   animation.play();
};

// I am assuming you can call these from your library

const onAnimationRender = nextFrame => recording.step(nextFrame);
const onAnimationEnd = () => recording.step(recording.stop);

let now = 0;
const progression = () => {
    now = now + 1 + recorder.error * fps / 1000;
    recorder.error = 0;
    return now * 1000 / fps / duration
}
```

I found this solution to be satisfying at 30fps in both Chrome and Firefox. I didn't experience the Chrome bugs mentionned by Kaiido and thus didn't implement anything to deal with them.

Comment: Interesting ! Does it works in 4K ? 
I made some test in 4k with my own implementation and the results were not good at all

Comment: My laptop is not suited for playing back 4k videos so I can't tell if it's choppy because of the recording or because of the playback. I did try recording a 2560 x 1440 DOM animation with html2canvas and I am pleased with the result. The average error per video frame is 0.09 ms with a peak at 3.66ms (in Firefox) and the duration of the output video is 1.006 times the one of the DOM animation. I did however feel the need to bump MediaRecorder's `videoBitsPerSecond` option because the default was too low and I found that choosing the right setting is too much of a trial and error process.

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/177) to get a grasp of  why even triggering pause and resume at the right pace will not necessarily produce a video with a reliable framerate. Although it is a nice simple solution for basic needs, I think it is better to render still images and send them to a local server if you need something professional looking.

Comment: I see this answer only now, and it works pretty well and is way simpler than my implementation (even works better in Firefox than mine). I should maybe get rid of these waitForEvents too if they don't help as I thought. For the Chrome bug, here is a repro: https://jsfiddle.net/g4dbxkou There should be no red in the output. Using a second canvas works-around that: https://jsfiddle.net/g4dbxkou/1

Comment: I tried adding a draw method from a video which plays in the background via a video element, and it fails with no apparent reason.. any idea why?

Comment: Also didn't work with img element from local image, even though it is displayed on the canvas.. weird

Comment: @mik I'm not sure what you mean, but I encourage you to post a distinct question with relevant code ad error messages.

Comment: That's the thing, it didn't write any error.. I mean that I tried to draw a video element or an image on the canvas, and it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by @geoffrey, but it still didn't produce ideal results, so I did some digging.

According to [mdn web docs for `captureStream(fps)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream), in regards to the `fps` argument:

> If not set, a new frame will be captured each time the canvas changes;

Wonderful, so even if I update my canvas once per second/day/fortnight, I still will get only frames that can be interpreted to be at a specific frame rate?

I tried doing `ffmpeg -i 'video.webm' frames/%05d.png`, but it didn't work out: I still got a bunch of undesired/duplicate frames exported. It was quite weird, since `ffmpeg` basically took a random frame-rate and went with it. I could use a deduplicate filter ffmpeg provides, but it seems hacky. What if two frames are almost identical? What if I want to have two identical frames recorded to imitate a pause in an animation?

I am no expert how the codecs work, but each frame gets assigned a timestamp, so we have a variable frame rate situation. After a few searches, I stumbled upon an article that answered my prayers:

https://superuser.com/questions/908295/ffmpeg-libx264-how-to-specify-a-variable-frame-rate-but-with-a-maximum

`-vsync` parameter set to `drop` does what I think I want:

> As passthrough but destroys all timestamps, making the muxer generate fresh timestamps based on frame-rate.

The adjusted command becomes `ffmpeg -i 'video.webm' -vsync drop frames/%05d.png`

Volia! I got a bunch of frames that seem to correspond to updates of canvas. Then its a simple case of stitching them back up to a video with something like: `fmpeg -framerate 60 -i "frames/%05d.png" -c:v libx264 -b:v 8M out.mp4`

### Notes

I couldn't find a way to directly convert from a VFR video to a fixed fps video without the intermediate step of generating a bunch of images.

When using `MediaRecorder`, the default codec option might limit the bitrate too much, I got better results with:

```js
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: `video/webm;codecs=h264,opus`,
    // 200 MBits/s
    // There seems to be an internal limit
    bitsPerSecond: 1024 * 1024 * 200,
    videoBitsPerSecond: 1024 * 1024 * 200,
});
```

Even setting a high bitrate might not be enough if recording too fast (recording at 60 fps). I had to manually throttle the "recording fps" to about 20fps to reduce encoding artefacts.

I'm rendering stuff with THREE.js, so probably canvas is updated only once per render. If doing multiple draws per desired frame (using canvas API f.e.), using a second canvas to copy over the result to trigger a recorded frame might be necessary.